# What to do next after finishing a project

Tags: career-development, clients, software

Me and my friend are 15 and 17 year olds who write applications for mobile phones in their spare time. A few months earlier, we were at a hacker games event (basically a startup competition), where we were given an offer to write an app for android. It was this moment we realised we could make money just by pressing buttons on our keyboards regardless of our age. We have already finished the project, and so we wanted more. We went to our local pizzeria and asked if they want an app in which you could order pizzas. The owner of the pizzeria seemed interested, he said he'd call us, but he didn't for almost 2 weeks now. The question is - what to do next? We want to earn money by programming, but we don't have any clients, especially ones who don't consider our age a problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could write the app and then try and sell it.

It's easier to sell a product that exists rather than an idea, especially to entrepreneurs who know what other peoples unrealised ideas are worth in time and money. Particularly if you have no reputation or qualifications standing behind you to say you can actually do it. Moreso if they can't see how it will affect their bottom line positively, since they've never needed one before, and if people want a pizza they can use their phone to order one just by calling rather than using an app.

Comment: If we do build an app before offering it to anyone, there's a certain risk we're taking - people may not find the app useful, and in that case we would waste a lot of time. And, after all, we can't find anyone to offer an app to

Comment: Of course there is a risk, business is all about calculating risks, investing time and money into products/services/sales. If you want to be spoonfed, it doesn't work like that unless you have backing or work for someone who is taking risks. If you want money just for ideas, become an academic. It wouldn't be wasted time, you'd learn how to sell a product and you'd learn how to make one that sells (training).

Comment: @Martis So you want the pizzeria to take on the risk, pay you for a product that may not work. Don't think I would want to take the risk. Prove to me that you can build me something useful and I **might** decide to buy it.

Comment: "If we do build an app before offering it to anyone, there's a certain risk we're taking" - welcome to the real world. You have just learned the difference between a business and a hobby.

Comment: @Martis Ok, so you want to make money without taking a risk. Good luck with that. I think that also shows why people would consider your age to be a problem.

Comment: I do not exacly expect to take no risk, i'm just trying to think of a way to minimize it. I guess it's not possible given our experience and age. We'll probably try to create an app, then sell it, just as @Kilisi suggested. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Minimise risk by developing something that is very useful and will make or save a business lots of money, rather than be a convenience service that doesn't create a revenue stream. Small businesses won't normally pay for those, and if they do, they'll pay very little.